# change URL format in PMWIKI

Tags: url, replace, seo, right-to-left, pmwiki

Hello guys wondering if someone can help me with this 
I have a fresh install of pmwiki 2.2.80 (latest now) .
I want to change the way pm wiki links pages , in default , it converts the words to Ucase . like if i link "my work" it will be "www.blablabla.com/wiki/pmwiki.php?site.MyWork"
it is ok for latin languages but when i want to use this script for RTL languages like arabic or persian , becase there are no uppercase version of letters , it links to a joint word which has no mean or non sense for SEO .
I want to change the way it links to pages like instead of "site.MyWork" it will create a link like "site.my_work" with underline instead of spaces . any ideas on this ?

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the [Page naming](http://www.pmwiki.org/wiki/Category/PageNaming) category of cookbook recipes to see if something fit your needs.

Anyway, in PmWiki you could easily provide a title and a description for a page, and use them in [links](http://www.pmwiki.org/wiki/PmWiki/Links).